# MKV to MP4 with avconv halfs FPS

Tags: mp4, h.264, frame-rate, avconv, mkv

I just tried to convert the following MKV on my root server (via ssh):

```
Video: MPEG4 Video (H264) 1280x720 25fps [Video]
Audio: Dolby AC3 48000Hz stereo 192kbps [Audio]
```

to a *.mp4 file using avconv. However, even if I'm using

```
avconv -i input.mkv  -c:v copy -c:a copy test.mp4
```

the output file looks like:

```
Video: MPEG4 Video (H264) 1280x720 12.5fps 3946kbps [Video]
Audio: Dolby AC3 48000Hz stereo 192kbps [Audio]
```

What I've tried yet:

```
-vsync 2, -r 25 (on In- & Output)
```

I have no clue what is going on here.

Since my desired output is `-c:a libvorbis` , I have to use avconv.

The complete console output: http://pastebin.com/zadhjuqq

My suggestion is that something is wrong with the input since avconv outputs

```
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'input.mkv':
```

Since the codec is h264, it should be:

```
Input #0, matroska,h264, from 'input.mkv':
```

shouldn't it?

Update:

I found a workaround using mkvextract, liba52dec, oggenc & MP4Box:

```
mkvextract tracks "input.mkv" 0:vid.h264
mkvextract tracks "input.mkv" 1:audio.ac3
a52dec audio.ac3 -o wav > audio.wav
oggenc audio.wav audio.ogg
MP4Box -add audio.ogg -add vid.h264 test2.mp4
```

Comment: You should provide a full mediainfo output from both videos, input and output, in such cases.

Comment: First you should remux the mkv with mkvmerge. This might fix the damaged time codes.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/wZRSBVUT

Maximum frame rate                       : 1 000.000 fps

what the heck.

Comment: You have a constant frame rate of 25 fps and an audio delay of 1 min 5 sec. This delay is lost in the output and there is a variable frame rate of 12.5 with that huge maximum. Can you recognize the audio delay in the mkv and have you tried a remux?

Comment: Nope, I can't recognise it in the MKV. It plays flawlessly in Media Player Classic (using ffdshow).

I will try to remux it now, edit incoming ;)

Comment: Or maybe not, didn't know that you can edit posts for only 5 minutes.

Remux result: http://pastebin.com/7Eh6PpUB 

So it didn't work. Seems to be an issue of the audio delay I guess.